# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. Fitting NB

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I am trying to fit an NB classifier onto some data of the form:

```py
label = [[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0...,0],[0,1,1,0,1,0,...,1],...]

features = [(['0.02','0.03','0.05','0.04','0.015']),([...])]

len(label[n]) # isn`t consistent and varies

len(features[n]) # 5 always

len(features[n][m]) # varies, and isn`t consistent
```

I understand I need the arrays to be consistent of the same dimensions, how can I do it? I have no clue and only loops come to my mind.

The error I am getting is

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: You need to use some table/matrix manager package like pandas or numpy and use their tables as your data holders.